# How to get a single data on click event from a set objects in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**I have been trying the whole day but didn't get it working.** Everything is working fine, but I can't get a single marker title when it gets clicked on the map. When the each of the marker gets clicked, I want the title of the marker to displayed in the  View as shown below.

```
    constructor(props){
      this.state = {
      locObject: [],
      title: '',
    }      
    {this.state.LocObject.map((marker, index) => {

    return (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={index}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: parseFloat(marker.altitude),
            longitude: parseFloat(marker.longitude),
          }}
          onCalloutPress={() => console.log("It is working")}
          image={markerImage}>

        <MapView.Callout>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.calloutStyle}
              onPress={() => this.markerClickHandler}
              underlayColor="#000"
            >
              <View style={styles.calloutText}>

                <Text style={styles.style_marker_text}>
                  {marker.lokation}
                  {"\n"}
                  {marker.altitude}

                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </MapView.Callout>
        </MapView.Marker>
      );

    })
}

<Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
```

Comment: What does markerClickHandler look like?

Comment: The markerClickHandler has no implementation. It is just an empty method. What should I include there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In markerClickHandler method, you should add the following line of code.

```
{this.setState({title: marker.title}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to set `state.title`, you can do the following:

```
onPress={() => {this.setState({title: marker.title})}
```

assuming that the field you're grabbing the value from on the `marker` object is called `title`.